# Why do the users who edit questions not turn the poor questions into the best ones?

Tags: support, post-ban

What are the mistakes which will get your account blocked from asking questions?
If others also have permission to edit our questions, why they don't turn the poor questions into the best ones. Every feature added one by one after getting the votes, so is there any down-vote limit for blocking from asking questions?

Comment: For one thing, editors aren't supposed to change the actual question, just how it is presented and explained. If the base question is poor, there's only so much that can be done

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Lots of questions there.

> What are the mistakes will make our account blocked from asking questions?

It's not public. However a lot of downvotes, a lot of closed questions, and a lack of upvotes will all hurt you. This applies to all questions, including those you or the community deleted.

> If others also have permission to edit our questions means why they don't make the poor questions into best one.

Because they can't read your mind. Because they don't have your code to paste in. Because fixing grammar, spelling, organization and formatting can only go so far.

> Every features added one by one after getting the votes, so there is any minus vote limit for block from asking questions?

No, the block is not based on your rep exactly. Most people with a block have a very low rep, but that is because downvotes take away rep and upvotes give it.

Comment: Are you sure you can't read minds? Parsing that question seems to suggest otherwise.

Comment: @apaul34208: If she could, she wouldn't even need to parse the question.

Answer (score 7):

We get flooded with poor questions every day.  Fortunately, many of them are blocked by the automated quality filter, but some of them still get through.  There simply isn't enough time in the day to provide individual attention to each one, and we feel that users should be putting their own effort into asking good questions anyway.

There is [plenty of help available](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to new users to make sure that they have every tool they need to ask a good question.